# Cannot get old values of multi-select dropdown in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, multi-select

How can I get **selected old values of multi-select dropdown** in the create form and the edit form?

```
<select name="team[]" id="team" class="selectpicker" multiple>
    @foreach ($tdropdown as $tdrop =>$id) 
       <option value="{{$id}}">{{$tdrop}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

I tried as follows in the create form:

```
<option value="{{ $id }}" {{ (collect(old( 'team' ))->contains($tdrop)) ? 'selected':'' }} {{ $tdrop,$employee->team ? 'selected' : ''}} > {{ $tdrop }}</option>
```

In the edit form:

```
<option value="{{ $id }}" {{ (collect(old( 'team' ))->contains($tdrop)) ? 'selected':'' }} {{ ($tdrop,$employee->team) ? 'selected' : ''}} > {{ $tdrop }}</option>
```

Please help me to get the multi-select old values in the edit form and create form. Thank you.

Comment: what does mean: `{{ $tdrop,$employee->team ? 'selected' : ''}}`

Comment: It means employee object and team field

Comment: is this correct syntax? I think comma broken.